# Реагирование на действия seekBar в списке ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-layout

Делаю кастомный `ListView` на андроид в котором имеется три текствьюшки, `ImageView` и `SeekBar`.
Никак не могу сообразить как сделать реагирование на перемещение `SeekBara` в каждом отдельном элементе `ListView`.

Ниже разметка элемента `ListView`.

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Разметка основного Layout.

**list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

И основной код **MainActivity.java**

```
package com.ofs.mif.slidebar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity

 {
    private static final String IMAGE_ITEM = "image";
    private static final String SUB_ITEM = "sub_item";

    String names[] = {"BEERЛОЖА","ХМЕЛЬНАЯ №1","ITALIANO","КАПИТАЛ","ШТАТ 51","ЙОХО","ПИВНОЙ ДВОР",
         "FERZ","ПЕТЦОЛЬДЪ","ПАРУС","МАМАДЖАН","РАШПЕР"
    };
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> myList;
    TextView txt1,txt2,txt3,txt4;
    ImageView img;
    int pos;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);
        Create_List();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        final SeekBar seekbar = (SeekBar)rowView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);

        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChangeListener);

        txt1 = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txt2 = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        txt3 = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        txt4 = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        img = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        seekbar.setMax(6);

    }
    private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChangeListener = 
            new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                //seekBar.setClickable(false);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(seekBar.getProgress() > 0) {
                    img.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    seekBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    txt1.setX(126 + 9*seekBar.getProgress());
                    txt2.setX(126 + 9*seekBar.getProgress());

                    txt4.setText(String.valueOf(seekBar.getProgress()) + " шт.");
                    img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource
                            (getResources(), Color.GREEN));
                    }
                    else {
                        img.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                        txt4.setText("");
                        seekBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
    };
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void Create_List(){
          ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
          myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
          HashMap<String, Object> hashmap;

          for(int i=0; i<=names.length-1;i++){
           hashmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
           hashmap.put(IMAGE_ITEM, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
           hashmap.put(SUB_ITEM, names[i]);
           myList.add(hashmap);
          }

          SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,myList,R.layout.activity_main,
            new String[]{IMAGE_ITEM,SUB_ITEM},    
            new int[]{R.id.imageView1, R.id.textView1}
            );

          list.setAdapter(adapter);
          }

}
```

Comment: изменять данные в адаптере листвью, и говорить адаптеру "перерисуй свой список, данные изменились"

Comment: Как? Что то не получается?

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую использовать свой адаптер для этих целей.
В этом адаптере и нужно для каждой ячейки делать обработчик!

Пример адаптера

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;

public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    textView.setText(values[position]);
    // Изменение иконки для Windows и iPhone
    String s = values[position];
    if (s.startsWith("Windows7") || s.startsWith("iPhone")
            || s.startsWith("Solaris")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no);
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
    }

    imageView.setOnclickListener(**ВАШ ОБРАБОТЧИК**)

    return rowView;
}
```

}

вызов в Activity

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" };
    MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

}
```

Comment: Может подскажите как?

Comment: Добавил! Можно посмотреть выше!

Comment: Попробовал Ваше предложение, но работает не очень корректно! Вы не могли бы по моим исходникам довать Ваш класс?

Comment: И как при этом добиться того чтобы при пролистывании списка пролистанные элементы не обновлялись?

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;
private final LayoutInflater inflater;

public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context                                                                           .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final DataHolder dataHolder;
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.лэйаут_с_текствью_и_сикбаром,null);
        dataHolder = new DataHolder();
        dataHolder.tv1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        dataHolder.tv2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        dataHolder.tv3 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        dataHolder.tv4 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView4);    
        dataHolder.seekBar = (SeekBar)view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        view.setTag(dataHolder);
    }
    else
        dataHolder = (DataHolder)view.getTag();

    String s = StringArray[position];
    dataHolder.tv1.setText(s);
    dataHolder.tv2.setText(s);
    dataHolder.tv3.setText(s);
    dataHolder.tv4.setText(s);
    dataHolder.seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    return view;
}

public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int position, boolean fromUser) {
    if (fromUser){
        //Пользователь тянет слайдер, чето делаем
    }
}

public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    //Пользователь начал тянуть слайдер
}

public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    //Пользователь окончил перетягивание слайдера
}

private class DataHolder
{
    TextView tv1;
    TextView tv2;
    TextView tv3;
    TextView tv4;    
    SeekBar seekBar;
}
```

Comment: Да все правильно!

Comment: Не могу понять! НО что то у меня не работает! Вы не могли бы по моим исходникам сверху показать как реализовать весь проект?